# What do empty curly brackets mean in bash?

Tags: bash

I understand all of this but lose it when i get to the 7th line starting with `find`. 
i don't understand the `-exec cp {}`. I understand that this is `executing` the `copy` command but I don't understand what the brackets`{}` are doing, especially if they are empty?

*This entire snippet is from a book im reading.*

```
# This script prompts to backup files and location
# The files will search on $HOME dir and will only backup files to same $HOME dir.
read -p "Which file types would you like to backup? >>: " file_suffix
read -p "Which directory would you like to backup to? >>: " dir_name
# creates a directory if it does not currently exist
test -d $HOME/$dir_name || mkdir -m 700 $HOME/$dir_name
# search criteria ie .sh . The -path, -prune and -o options are to exclude the back directory from the backup.
find $HOME -path $HOME/$dir_name -prune -o -name "*$file_suffix" -exec cp {} $HOME/$dir_name/ \;
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{}` has no particular meaning to `bash`, but does mean something to `find`.

```
find . -exec stat {} ";"
```

Will recursively stat every file reachable from the current working directory with a single invocation of `stat` per file.

```
find . -exec stat {} "+"
```

will run `stat` with multiple files at once.

You can convince yourself that the `{}` are really not part of the shell syntax by quoting it or using a variable.

```
find . -exec stat "{}" ";"

A="{}" find . -exec stat "$A" ";"
```

will produce the same ouptut as the first example.

Comment: Just for info, + (the plus sign) is not a shell metacharacter so it doesn't need quoting/escaping. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659355/321265

Answer (score 0):

If the string {} appears anywhere in the utility name or the arguments it is replaced by the pathname of the current file (found by 'find'). So, in your example, copy {the file that find finds} to $HOME/$dir_name/

Comment: thanks, all of the responses were very helpful, your explanation made it relatable. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It means the result of the `find` command, passed as an argument to `exec`:

Let us say that the result of the `find` command is `x`, then:

```
find ..... -exec echo "{}"
```

will give output `x`, because `x` is passed as an argument and this argument is represented by `{}`.

In your case, find will give files with the property `-path $HOME/$dir_name -prune -o -name "*$file_suffix"` and these files will be represented to `cp` command by `{}` (one by one not all together).

Comment: thanks, you made this much clearer.