# Does + need to be escaped in find commands?

Tags: bash, find, quoting

I have the following code in bash and I wonder on whether I can get rid of `\+` and simply use `+`

```
   find "$fdir"                                \
      -type f -name "*.org" -o -name "*.texi"  \
      -exec head -n "$n" {} \+                 \
   | grep --color -e ^ -e '^==>.*'
```

Answer (score 7):

`+` is **not** a special character in any shell and doesn't need quoted.

`^` is special in a few shells though including the Thompson shell (first UNIX shell), Bourne shell, `fish`, `rc`, `es`, `zsh` with `extendedglob`. [`{}` needs to be quoted in  `rc`, and older versions of `fish`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247786). `*`, `(`, `)`, `>` are special in most shells.

Note that not all `head` implementations accept more than one argument. The GNU implementation of `head` does and will print those `==>` header lines but only when passed more than one argument or with the `-v` option.

Also note that AND (implied) has precedence over OR (`-o`) in `find` (see [`find` with multiple `-name` and `-exec` executes only the last matches of `-name`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191)), so:

```
find "$fdir"                                       \
   -type f '(' -name '*.org' -o -name '*.texi' ')' \
   -exec head -v -n "$n" '{}' +                    \
   | grep --color -e '^' -e '^==>.*'
```

(using `'...'` quoting in place of `"..."` or `\` quoting for consistency only).

would work in Bourne-like, csh-like shells and `fish`. In `rc`/`es`, you'd need to remove the double quotes. In csh/tcsh, you'd replace `"$fdir"` with `$fdir:q` so it works even if `$fdir` contained newline characters.

The quotes around `$fdir` and `$n` are only needed in Bourne-like shells other than `zsh` and csh-like shells. `"` is not a quoting operator in `rc`/`es`. `\` is not a quoting operator in `rc` either (though does do line continuation like in other shells).

See [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141) for what characters are special in which shell and how to escape / quote them.

Comment: Why do you include `'('` and `')'`.

Comment: @Pietru, because AND has precedence over OR, so `-type f -name '*.org' -o -name '*.texi' -exec...` is actually interpreted as `'(' -type f -name '*.org' ')' -o '(' -name '*.texi' -exec... ')'`. See [\`find\` with multiple \`-name\` and \`-exec\` executes only the last matches of \`-name\`](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191)

Comment: Thank you Stéphane

Comment: Shame the question in the title ("Does + need ...?") and the question in the body ("Can I get rid of...?") are logical opposites. I read "Does + need to be escaped?" and then the answer "Yes", and got confused.

Comment: @jaimet, I've now removed the "yes" to avoid the possible confusion